# What kind of rubber hose to use with fuel vapor line?

Tags: fuel-system, hose

I need to replace a fuel evaporation rubber hose and the OEM hose is no longer made.  I was looking through McMaster Carr and saw that there were hoses specifically for fuel and specifically for air.

For a fuel evaporation line, do I need to use a rubber hose that's rated for fuel?  Or does a rubber hose rated for air work as well?

Comment: Fuel vapor = fuel.  Keep it simple.  You really need a fuel compatible material. With that said your use of the word _rubber_ is very misleading.  I believe you intended to use the word _flexible_ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you really need a flexible hose that is compatible with fuel.  From a glance at a materials specification, I think you should be looking for a hose made from Nitrile.  Other compatible materials include Viton, Fluorosilicone but those are not as common as Nitrile.    Polyurethane is rated as "fair" for compatibility with Gasoline.  [Reference](https://mykin.com/rubber-chemical-resistance-chart-3)

With that said, I suspect the easiest and least expensive place to obtain fuel vapor hosing would be at your local autoparts store.  They sell the stuff by the inch.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hose rated for fuel. The hose needs to have to same properties regardless if fluid is a vapor or liquid.